Can I use dd to repeat printf output?
I want to generate many test bin files which consists of their binary number, like:

b1.bin

0000 0001 0000 0001
0000 0001 0000 0001


b2.bin

0000 0002 0000 0002
0000 0002 0000 0002

and so on.
For every single bin file, since it is slow using bash loop to generate the repeated 'xxxx' by appending, I try to use printf piping dd instead.
However, when I used printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01' | dd bs=4 count=1024 of=test.bin, I always got only 4 bytes copied to test.bin. I expected it would be 4096 bytes.
Is it valid to use pipe like this? Or was there any point I didn't notice?

You only provided 4 input bytes. Check dd --help or man dd for a description of the parameters: count=N : copy only N input blocks

You could try printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01%.0s' {1..1024} | dd bs=4 count=1024 and see if that's any faster than traditional bash looping. Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times

Well, if you say printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01'  | dd bs=4 count=1024 of=test.bin, I would expect 8 bytes. What about for i in {1..1024}; do printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01'; done | dd bs=4 count=1024 of=test.bin? I'd expect 4096 bytes. I'm also not sure about the purpose of dd which does nothing here.

I'm also not sure whether you want a file full of bytes (which is what you do) or full of ASCII blocks consisting of printable representations of 4 bit blocks printed using blocks of four 0 and 1 characters.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, I would like a file full of bytes. And I realizes I do not need dd here, thanks.

you want 'full bytes' but you also want a) a space between each byte and b) a \n at the 'end' of each 4 bytes?  or have you added the extra white space in your examples for readability? it might help with clarification if you were to provide the first couple lines of output from xxd or od -c

You don't need dd for that.
printf '%.s\0\0\0\1' {1..1024} >b1.bin


As indicated in comments: No, dd only allows you to select a smaller part of the input; it does not have a way to arbitrarily loop over it or generate new output. The count= argument simply says to stop after that many records have been processed from the input.
The printf trick in Oguz Ismail's answer is nice. A less compact but more obvious solution is to use a regular Bash loop, but you apparently think that's too slow. Maybe then use an external utility to generate the repetitions? Here's Perl.
perl -e 'print "\x00\x00\x00\x01" x 1024' >b0001.bin

Perhaps also explore Perl's pack("N", number) for getting an unsigned 32-bit integer into a sequence of four bytes in big-endian order.
You are not revealing how exactly you tried to do this in Bash, but we can speculate about reasons it might be slower than necessary.
One such reason is if you repeatedly append in a loop. Compare:
# XXX FIXME: Inefficient
> b0001.bin
for((i=0; i<1024; ++i)); do
    printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01' >>b0001.bin
done

which reopens the file handle for appending and seeks to the end of the file again and again inside the loop, and
for((i=0; i<1024; ++i)); do
    printf '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
done >b0001.bin

which avoids that (and also does away with the need to explicitly empty the file before the loop, in case the file already exists and you want to ensure that you properly overwrite any previous contents).
The three-argument for loop is also more clunky but less memory-intensive than building a list of 1024 numbers in memory just so you can loop over it with {1..1024}. That's not a massive amount of memory, but if you are doing this in a loop, too, not doing it repeatedly should shave off a few more percentage points.
Even then, Bash is hideously slow. Here are timings from my Mac (including for comparison one of the solutions from How to make files with specific HEX pattern in Bash? and using those parameters to make results comparable):
tripleee@bash$ time for((i=0; i<78643200; ++i)); do printf '\x12\x34\x56\x78'; done >/dev/null

real    14m13.734s
user    7m10.944s
sys 6m56.456s

tripleee@bash$ time printf '%.s\x12\x34\x56\x78' {1..78643200} >/dev/null

real    2m50.514s
user    2m0.688s
sys 0m32.440s

tripleee@bash$ time jot -s "" -b $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' $((300*1024*1024)) >/dev/null

real    0m41.274s
user    0m40.530s
sys 0m0.471s

tripleee@bash$ time perl -e 'print "\x12\x34\x56\x78" x 78643200' >/dev/null

real    0m0.584s
user    0m0.161s
sys 0m0.381s

This is on a 2018 15-inch MacBook Pro running MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1 and Bash  5.2.26(1)-release from Homebrew.

Yeah, the former was how I did it. I do not know we can use for loop like the latter, thank you.
